# Django-Filter over Managers

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter, django-managers

I've been stuck in this for several weeks now and I believe the answer is super simple but somehow I can't find it anywhere online. Which makes me think I'm going about it totally wrong.

All I want to do is be able to filter my stats such as the `get_largest_winning_trade` function based on the [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/) package. Where am I going wrong? As a side note `get_largest_winning_trade` is showing the largest winning trade in the Trade Model but it is not being filtered for my criteria. Such as "user".

managers.py

```
from django.db import models

class TradeQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def get_users_trades(self, username):
        return self.filter(user__username=username)

class TradeManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return TradeQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def get_users_trades(self, username):
        return self.get_queryset().get_users_trades(username)

    def get_largest_winning_trade(self):
        return max([t.profit_loss_value_fees for t in self.all()])
```

views.py

```
class StatsView1(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Trade
    template_name = 'dashboard/stats1.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        filter = StatsFilter1(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = filter
        context['get_largest_winning_trade'] = Trade.objects.get_largest_winning_trade
        return context
```

stats.html (testing)

```
        filter.qs.get_largest_winning_trade: {{ filter.qs.get_largest_winning_trade }} <br>
        Trade.get_largest_winning_trade: {{ Trade.get_largest_winning_trade }} <br>
        trade.get_largest_winning_trade: {{ trade.get_largest_winning_trade }} <br>
        get_largest_winning_trade: {{ get_largest_winning_trade }} <br>  # works but not with filter
```

---

**Additional Requested Information**

Shared the class, it's quite long so I tried to reduce it to what is most helpful. Please let me know if there's anything else.

models.py

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Trade"
        verbose_name_plural = "Trades"
     ...

     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
     status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='cl')
     type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=LONG)
     broker = models.ForeignKey(Broker, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
     asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, default=DEFAULT_ASSET_ID, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
     #AUTOMATED FIELDS
     profit_loss_value_fees = models.FloatField(null=True)
     objects = TradeManager()
     ...

     def save(self):
         ...
         self.profit_loss_value_fees = self.get_profit_loss_value_fees()
         return super(Trade, self).save()

     ...
```

Comment: someone downvoted but never left a comment why.. not very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can do something like this using [`qs`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs) property:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    filter = StatsFilter1(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter'] = filter
    context['get_largest_winning_trade'] = filter.qs.get_largest_winning_trade
    return context
```

### Update

I think rather than doing it manager, you can do the calculation here with [`aggregation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/). Like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max
...

context['get_largest_winning_trade'] = filter.qs.aggregate(max_value=Max('profit_loss_value_fees'))['max_value']
```

Reason for using aggregation is to reduce DB hits, because your manager method will hit database multiple times during loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the potential answer @ruddra! That only gets me an error message of  'TradeQuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_largest_winning_trade'

Comment: Can you please share the models?

Comment: Waaaa I think you solved it! This has been such a thorn in my side for so long, will go through more stats calculations tomorrow and post here if I've discovered anything else that could benefit this answer. Thanks again!